# Take a specific data from the CSV file and use it on the loop

Tags: python, pandas

So basically I want to create a loop. I want to take a specific data from the CSV file and check it with a condition and say True or False. If it says true I want it to get printed. And like that I want every data from the same column to run on the loop. And just like that the loop continues.

```
import pandas as pd

CSV_file = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

name = CSV_file['Name']
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3653 in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:147 in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:176 in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7080 in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7088 in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Name'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Documents/demooajdo.py:6
    name = CSV_file['Name']

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3761 in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3655 in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'Name'
```

I want to know how I can take the specific value from a specific column and row.

For now lets say this is the csv file

```
Name   Age   location
Ben.   21    NY
Jack   22    Texas
Mark   23    LA
Joao   34    Lisbon
Juan   24    Madrid
```

Comment: CSV stands for Comma-Separated Values. There are no commas in your CSV file.

Comment: So the file just has one column, its name is `Name   Age   location`.

Comment: If the file uses TAB separators, use `sep='\t'` in the `read_csv()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV file doesn’t have a column named “Name”.

Take a look at: `print(CSV_file.columns)` to see what the actual column names are.
You might also look at `CSV_file.dtypes` while you’re at it.

Answer (score 0):

When using `pd.read_csv()`, you can try to explicitly pass the following arguments:

- `pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0)`: force the first row (indexed 0) of the CSV to be used as column names. Default is `'infer'` but it rarely works in my experience,
- `pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['Name', 'Age', 'location'])`: explicitly define the column names if everything else fails. You will probably want to set `skiprows=0` too if your column names are actually in the CSV, so the first row will be discarded.

Anyway, you will need to `print(CSV_file)` or `display(CSV_file)` to have a look at your actual dataframe content, because it is obviously not what you are expecting.

If you actually have the columns names in the first row, it might still be a problem of content type or formatting (which Pandas infers… not always right). So you may also need to force a conversion to string on the first row.